# Differences of rows and adding the results in a new row

Tags: python, pandas

I want the results of this line of code `df.diff(periods=len(df)-1)` in a new row of my data frame.

The line of code above calculates the difference between the first and the last row. So what I want is to add a new line with the results to compare later in percentages the trend of my data. I have explained the final goal in case there exists a more straightforward approach.

My data

```
#MetaHash           0x        1inch      88mph        AC  \
Time                                                                         
14:00 16/03/2021   196876.0  162052086.0  279895846.0   850387.0  713496.0   
14:02 16/03/2021   271687.0  150463819.0  281510814.0   850387.0  714325.0   
14:49 16/03/2021   362927.0  164764136.0  278248431.0   862865.0  688467.0
```

And the results obtained after applying the line of code.

```
                #MetaHash           0x        1inch      88mph        AC  \
Time                                                                         
14:00 16/03/2021        NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN       NaN   
14:02 16/03/2021        NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN       NaN     
17:15 17/03/2021        NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN       NaN   
11:46 18/03/2021   362810.0  270883348.0  115643691.0  1833585.0 -312283.0 # I want this row in my previous data frame I have shown above.
```

Comment: `df.append(df.iloc[-1].sub(df.iloc[0]).rename('whateveryouwant'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `concat()` method:-

```
import pandas as pd    
df=pd.concat((df,df.diff(periods=len(df)-1).dropna()))
```